# Long running time

Tags: integral-equations, output

I gave this data as input:

```
Integrate[((x+z) EllipticE[-((4 Subscript[b, 1] Subscript[b, 2])/((x+z)^2+(Subscript[b,1]-Subscript[b, 2])^2))])/(Sqrt[(x+z)^2+(Subscript[b, 1]-Subscript[b, 2])^2] ((x+z)^2+(Subscript[b, 1]+Subscript[b, 2])^2)),{x,a,-a}]
```

However, It took forever to process the input and calculate the definite integral. After an hour or so it gave me the outpust same as input. I know it is a bit complicated bu I have no idea how to simplify the input. I also use Assuming command to help processing but it didn't change anything. It again took forever to compute the input and gave me the output same as input. What should I do?

P.S:I am running Mathematica 10.0

Comment: @Bill So should I use version 9 or is there no way to solve this input in mathematica?